# Transfer data between steps spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

Can anyone explain me how to transfer the variable values between steps in spring batch?

in step1, I read table and store the values in variables. Now i need to use those variables to update the table in step2.

Comment: Read my answer and let me know if you need anything else .

Answer (score 0):

In spring batch data can be shared between steps by using `jobexecutionContext`. Spring batch has a table with the name "*BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT*".

So in any of the step, you can easily get `jobExecutionContext` and put the variable and its value. Basically it is a Map of key and value pairs. The same stored values can be accessed in any of the step throughout the job.

Read [this](http://kechengpuzi.com/q/s8117060) for better understanding of the concept.

Comment: The Link is broken